# Make return type of function dependent on other field of object while within constructor of class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type a generic class which takes a specific object in their constructor. The object has a field of type `R` and it should have a function `test` which returns whatever `R` is. This function should also get a parameter of type `T` which I want to hand into the generic.

So e.g.:

```
new SomeClass<number>({
  type: 'I hand in a string',
  test: (thisVariableShouldNowBeTypedNumber) => {
    return 'I should now have to return a string'
  },
})
```

The way I thought this should work was

```
class R1 {
  async resolve(): Promise<string> { return 'asd' }
}
class R2 {
  async resolve(): Promise<{ asd: number }> { return {asd:123} }
}

type R = R1 | R2

type Args<X, T extends R> = {
  type: T
  test:  (x:X) => T,
}

class A<X, T extends R = any> {
  constructor(a: Args<X, T>) {}
}
```

The problem I am running into is, the moment I say `new SomeClass<number>` instead of just using `new SomeClass` the function `test` gets the return type `any`.

```
new A({
  type: new R2(),
  test: (x) => { // tst has type (x:unknown) => R2
    return new R2()
  },
})


new A<number>({
  type: new R2(),
  test: (x) => { // tst has type (x:number) => any
    return new R2()
  },
})
```

I created a [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCM0DeBYAUNakCeA7Y0ATgKYQD2IAbsQBQCUAXNAAqFkC2AlhMQDwQAXQp1wBzAHzIixAQFdCuaAHJIAEyXQAvum1pQkGLABMydJhz5p5KrUYs2XHryRYIqprlnsARsUJbJFxI5BWQ1BngjAGZNLR10dAFsAAdiOGgAXjhEAB84IwS0JNToAEFCUQheAA0AGmgAFWhiAA8BYlxVQ0ks1AxoYuImBrMB0gEmaBoWhmq6TMkG2vi0dH0oMpr6ptb2zsNMrFxsQNHgMlxBQllgATJCGjAmcsqtxvF5pF1ddFxiAHcyjQ+phBh4Afl6Mt+u1BExpvMMoFoAB6FFjQTQAAWkAGKTS0wYslwAGtcGR-rhEZJjKNMMF5Io-oDjPRRppoZo6IVfhDSrxPD4-OJgaMwdBmZC6NDQeN4S1qVI0RiBNjcYMpjNBb5CIqwMc6dIQkyIazuf0OTo6EA) trying to isolate the issue as much as possible.

If I do not have the parameter `x` it seems to be working fine. I suppose ts is getting confused having one generic set and the other one still to be inferred?

Comment: Afaik, TypeScript cannot infer optional type parameters if you supply any type parameter. You'll need to use `new A<number, R2>`

Comment: Ahh, that would be a bummer, but it would explain my issue. I will have a look into this, thanks :-)

Comment: I think it is indeed the same problem. I voted to close the question as a duplicate.